# Incorrect displayed ListView Android

Tags: java, android

I have to display objects from SQLite db to a listView. I tried it, but I can't find the problem why i can't see a half of the first object, and a half of the last. What can be the problem?
screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KR9rf.png

Class of Adapter:

```
public class ReminderListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Reminder> {
private Context mContext;
private int mResource;
OnItemClickListener listener;


public ReminderListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<Reminder> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    mContext = context;
    mResource = resource;

}

public void setListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    final int id = getItem(position).getId();
    final String name = getItem(position).getName();
    String hour = getItem(position).getHour();
    String date = getItem(position).getDate();


        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);
    Button delbtn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button4);
    //Button editbtn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button5);
        final TextView resId = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textId);
        final TextView resName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
        final TextView resHour = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textHour);
        final TextView resDate = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textDate);

        resId.setText(String.valueOf(id));
        resName.setText(name);
        resHour.setText(hour);
        resDate.setText(date);


   delbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           listener.OnItemClick(v, position, id);
       }
    });

    return convertView;
}}
```

XML:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/main_background"
android:id="@+id/content"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".EditActivity">

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/item_color_state"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/item_color_state"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="4dp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/ListOfReminders"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```

I checked this xml file a lot of times, but I can't find my error. I constraint the bottom of listView to my bottom navigation bar, and the top to the top of parrent, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should remove this line from **`ListView`** and your problem can be solved.

> Remove this
>
> ```
>    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation"
> ```

and

> Add this Code and your problem fully solved
>
> ```
>    android:paddingBottom="200dp"
> ```